# Most simple way to avoid code duplication in razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, duplicates

What is the most simplest way to asp dotnet core 2.1 to avoid code duplication. I have a questionnaire and for exampel for question type number I have a code like so.

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="control-label col-md-4 offset-md-0 pt-2">@question.Text:</label>
<div class="col-md-2" question-validation key="@question.Id">
    @{
        var key = question.Id.ToString();
        string value = null;
        if (Model.Answers.ContainsKey(key) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Answers[key]))
        {
            value = Model.Answers[question.Id.ToString()];
        }
    }
    <div class="form-group" >
        <input class="form-control" type="text" question-type="@QuestionType.Number" question-id="@question.Id" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" value="@value">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to use this code multiple times on single page but I don't want to duplicate the code.

Comment: you can use PartialView or ViewComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sure way is to make that code a `PartialView` once a partial view you can then call it anywhere and pass the model to it

```
<partial name="myPartialView" />
//Or with a model
@(await Html.PartialAsync("myPartialView", modelToPass))
```